# How to add dependencies to an Eclipse e4 RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm developing an Eclipse e4 RCP application and want to use the Jersey REST client to call a RESTful webservice, but when I add the dependencies to the plugin `MANIFEST.MF` file the application fails to start correctly.

The dependencies I want to add are `javax.ws.rs`, `org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client` and `org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-json-jackson`. All three have been added to the target definition file which are being downloaded from Eclipse Orbit (so they already include the necessary OSGI information) and the plugin `MANIFEST.MF` file.

The project is comprised of two plugin modules, a feature module which specifies the two plugins, a product module which specifies the feature, and a target definition module. The first plugin is `com.xxx.application` and is main application. The second plugin is `com.xxx.demo` and provides a part for the main application. It is the second plugin which I'm trying to add the dependencies.

When I try to start the application via the product file, the following error message is returned...

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-05-02 14:52:36.033
!MESSAGE Unable to retrieve the bundle from the URI: bundleclass://com.xxx.demo/com.xxx.demo.DemoPart
```

The problem seems to occur the moment any of the three dependencies are added to the `com.xxx.demo` plugin's `MANIFEST.MF` file and if I remove the dependencies from the `MANIFEST.MF` file it starts correctly. I haven't included any of the JAX-RS code in the plugin which would call the web service, so I know the problem is triggered when I add the dependencies to the manifest file.

Is there something I've missed in setting up the dependencies which is preventing the application from starting or alternatively is there a better way add dependencies to a plugin?

Comment: If you are using a feature build for the product every plugin must be listed in one of the features. Add them to your feature if they are not in anything else.

Comment: I've just tried adding the `javax.ws.rs` dependency to both the plugin's `MANIFEST.MF` file and `feature.xml` file and the RCP application starts. However if I do the same with `org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client` then I get the same error message again. Are dependencies transitive in Eclipse RCP or do I need to add everything in the dependency hierarchy into the feature?

Comment: After some further experimentation I've managed to get the application to start by adding all the dependencies for `org.glassfish.jersey.core.jersey-client` and `org.glassfish.jersey.media.jersey-media-json-jackson` so I'm guessing that the dependencies aren't transitive.

Comment: The MANIFEST.MF for a plugin generally only has to list other plugins it depends on diectly. The feature.xml files in the product must list every single plugin that is required in the RCP.

Comment: Thanks - If you want to post your comments as an answer then I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MANIFEST.MF for a plugin generally only has to list other plugins it depends on directly.

When using a feature based .product file the feature.xml files in the product must list every single plugin that is required in the RCP. If something isn't listed it won't be included.